# android data save directories

Tags: android, filesystems, directory

My application is mostly c++ (using NDK) so I use `fopen`, `fwrite`, etc. standard functions to create and game save files and write into them.

When I use `fopen("game.sav", "wb")`, it appears that it's being created at path

`/data/user/10/com.my.game/files/game.sav`.

My app is multi-user. So I want to have a separated folders where users store their save-files. And instead of the path above I'd like to have paths like

`/data/user/10/com.my.game/files/user0/game.sav`,

`/data/user/10/com.my.game/files/user1/game.sav`, etc

My app's frontend is in Java, and when new user is being registered, I want to create a folder `/data/user/10/com.my.game/files/user0/`. But I don't know how to do it, because

```
final File newDir = context.getDir("user0", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

results in path being created at `/data/user/10/com.my.game/app_user0` that's a different path.

It is possible to create folders at `/data/user/10/com.my.game/files/` and how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple way to do it,** this code you can change it suit many conditions. If you know that your path is different from what getFilesDir() gets you then you can create a File first of all by using a path that you know and the last 2 lines of code will still be same.

```
    File file = this.getFilesDir(); // this will get you internal directory path
    Log.d("BLA BLA", file.getAbsolutePath());
    File newfile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/foo"); // foo is the directory 2 create
    newfile.mkdir();
```

**And if you know the path to "files" directory:**

```
     File newfile2 = new File("/data/data/com.example.stackoverflow/files" + "/foo2");
    newfile2.mkdir();
```

Both code works.

**Proof of Working:**

[image: Proof of working:]